# Tray icon problem in xfce and gnome with any icon theme

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, xfce, desktop-icons

On the **GNOME** and **xfce4** desktops tray icon's do not show applications status correctly. for example when **obs-studio** Records the desktop or is in pause mode No symbols are displayed on the obs tray icon.

When i use linux default icons theme like : **Adwaita** or **Breeze** everything is fine BUT i wanna install another popular icon themes like **arc** , **papirus** , **paper** and ... :
[image]
[image]

I traied many ways but This problem seems to be related to icon themes or DE !

I tested on **Gnome 41** and **xfce4**.

Can I use special theme only for tray that are separate from the theme icons of the entire system ? for example papirus for all desktop icons and Adwaita for only tray icons ???

Comment: Please specify version of Ubuntu where the issue appears. Ubuntu 21.10 comes with Gnome 40, not 41.

Comment: @vanadium i use arch btw. this problem not related to distro

Comment: Sorry, we do not support icon issues occurring on Arch.

Comment: @vanadium this problem is desktop problem and not related to distro type and version! i tested on ubuntu and linux-mint ...